# LCDs larger than 20x04 and 5" diagonal

Tags: lcd, i2c

Are there any i2c LCD screens that are larger than 2004 characters and larger than 4.8 x 2.7 x 1.2 inches in dimensions?

I have the [Sainsmart 2004 LCD](https://www.sainsmart.com/products/20x4-iic-i2c-twi-lcd-module) but it can't display all the information that I need. Maybe a 20x8 character screen? Because the screen will be viewed from a distance of about 50cm, the screen size should be at least 5" in diagonal.

[image]

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: No, but you can fake it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Fake it, as in use multiple LCDs over i2c? Are 20x04 LCDs as large as they get?

Comment: As in configure a MCU with a font table as a I2C slave and hook it up to a graphical LCD.

Answer (score 1):

Naked displays... search e.g. Ebay for "40x4 lcd" (maybe enable "worldwide" search)...

...naked... so not i2c ... but Arduino libs for these displays exist (e.g.: [liquidcrystal440](https://code.google.com/p/liquidcrystal440/)), so add an Arduino-Pro or such and you can have i2c... basically they are two 40x2 displays on the same spi bus selected by different chip select lines...

Answer (score 1):

The 44780 display chip used by these devices has 80 bytes of storage, which is why you can scroll the 2x16 side to side to show up to 40 characters per line. however 4x20 is 80 and that's the limit of the chip.

Answer (score 0):

There are ST7920 based displays which may come close to what you are looking for. They have a similar parallel (4 or 8 bit) interface to the HD44780 based displays (as you have been using), but also support a 3-wire SPI-like interface.

A quick google found the datasheet here:
https://www.lcd-module.de/eng/pdf/zubehoer/st7920_chinese.pdf

They have both graphics and text modes, and most of the displays appear to have 128x64 pixels, giving 16x8 characters assuming 8x8 font, although it appears the native text font is 16x8 pixels.

While it might be more complicated to use these in graphics mode, they are probably the closest to the HD44780 based displays in appearance (large monochrome pixels), unlike other large displays which will probably have more (smaller) pixels than you need.

See also https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/LCD12864